# How to find out Firstin LastOut of Night Shift Employee in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can get FirstIn - LastOut out of Day shift employee using min(),max(). But i have problem for night shift employee like 5:30 Pm to next day Morning 2:30 am. At the same day(Next day) they will come again on 5:30 pm. So I could not able to calculate..

Ex: Shift Table

```
  UserID     ShiftName    Start   End     
   2267     Night Shift-1  17:30  02:30
```

Ex: Employee Table :

```
   UserID     LogIn                   LogOut                         LogDate
    2267   2016-01-04 20:52:08.000  2016-01-04 22:09:22.000   2016-01-04 00:00:00.000
    2267   2016-01-04 23:00:07.000  2016-01-04 23:00:07.000   2016-01-04 00:00:00.000
    2267   2016-01-05 00:35:46.000  2016-01-05 00:35:46.000   2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
    2267   2016-01-05 01:02:31.000  2016-01-05 03:57:16.000   2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
    2267   2016-01-05 18:43:50.000  2016-01-05 19:05:04.000   2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
    2267   2016-01-05 19:10:20.000  2016-01-05 22:26:00.000   2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
    2267   2016-01-05 23:27:24.000  2016-01-05 23:27:24.000   2016-01-05 00:00:00.000
    2267   2016-01-06 03:45:16.000  2016-01-06 03:45:16.000   2016-01-06 00:00:00.000
```

I want output :

```
        EmpId     date           FirstIN    LastOUT
        2267    2016-01-04        20:52      03:57
        2267    2016-01-05        18:43      03:45
```

Comment: @Gordon Ok I have done

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work better with `lead()`.  Get the "out" date on the same row and then do the aggregation:

```
select userid, cast(logdate as date) as thedate,
       min(logdate), max(next_logdate)
from (select l.*,
             lead(logdate) over (partition by userid order by logdate) as next_logdate
      from logintable l
     ) l
where l.details = 'In'
group by userid, cast(logdate as date)
order by userid, cast(logdate as date);
```

(This isn't doing the conversion back to time to focus on the important part of the logic.)

Note:  this assumes the the next log record for an `'In'` record is always an `'Out'` record.  This is true of the data in your question.

Comment: @Godon : Thank you.. I will try... :)

Comment: @Godon  I can already got it.  I can get daytime Empoyee First in Last out. I have edited now want i am expecting.  Thanks in advance.